# Artinian rings and associated prime ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. Show that $R$ is artinian ring if and only if there exists a finite length $R$-module $M$, such that
>   $$\{r\in R \mid rm=0 ,\forall m\in M\}=(0).$$

The only thing I can think of is that I need to find $M$ such that $\mathrm{Ass}_{R}M=(0)$, but I'm not sure how to do this. $\mathrm{Ass}_{R}M$ is the set of all associated prime ideals of $M$.

Comment: What if $R$ is not a domain?

Comment: @Matt, I'm sorry I did not get your question.

Comment: I think he was pointing out that finding $M$ such that $\mathrm{Ass}_R M = \{0\}$ is not the way to go, as $0$ might not be a prime ideal in $R$.

Comment: @i.a.m If you succeed in showing that $\{0\}$ is prime, then your Artinian ring is a domain, but a commutative Artinian domain is a field. Since this is supposed to work for all Artinian rings, red flags should go up about this line of attack on the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, one direction is easy.  If $R$ is artinian then take $M = R$.

For the other direction , the given $M$ is both artinian and noetherian because it has finite length.  As it's noetherian take a finite set of generators $m_i$ and define $R \to M^n$ by $a \mapsto (am_i)$.  The condition on the annihilator of $M$ makes this injective so $R$ is a submodule of an artinian module and hence artinian.

Comment: for the first part, take M=R, why this will be of finite length? is the following true, R is an artinian ring then R is noetherian? and is the same statement true for modules? thank you.

Comment: Yes, a ring is artinian if and only if it is noetherian and dimension zero.  The proof is too long to type into a comment but it's widely known so if you google for it you will find plenty of sources.

Comment: Ok got it, can you please explain $M^n$ i'm not sure I understand the definitions of the map correctly

Comment: $M^n$ are $n$-tuples of elements in $M$.  So for example $M^3$ are tuples of the form $(a, b, c)$ where $a, b, c \in M$.  If the generators of $M$ are $\{m_1, m_2, \ldots, m_n\}$ then the map is $a \mapsto (am_1, am_2, \ldots, am_n)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it. Thank you again.